# Recycling views in a scrollview in Android

Tags: android, memory-management, android-recyclerview

In my application, I have a large, memory intensive layout for a fragment which consists of:

-an ImageView header

-a horizontal recyclerview with images

-another horizontal recyclerview with images

-around 10 imageviews (varies from session to session)

-textviews in between

all wrapped in a scrollview.

Now obviously, many devices do not like this layout because of all the images being loaded, even when resizing them to the dimensions of their imageviews.
Is there any way to manually tell a view to recycle itself when it's offscreen?  I have no idea how to implement a recyclerview which can hold all these different view types (and a variable number of them).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed most OOM errors by making the varialbe length list a recyclerview and disabling it's nested scroll behavior.